# Storing and returning custom user_meta_data in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, variables, persistence

I'm building a simple Wordpress "Course" website. Each user has to fully watch a video and when the video is complete it opens up the next one.

Currently, I have an `update_user_meta` tied to my video `end()` function but after I get that information into the database I'm unsure of how to pull it back out with `get_user_meta` to treat it almost like a user specific persistent session. Any thoughts from anyone? Or is my approach wrong?

This is what I have so far based off of this: https://patrickshampine.com/2014/updating-user-meta-admin-ajax-frontend/

html:

```
<dl class="accordion">
  <dt><a class="checkbox" id="video-1" href="">Instructions</a></dt>
  <dd class="video" id="dd-1">
    <p id="video-message"></p>
    <p id="wistia_id" class="wistia_embed" style="width:640px;height:360px;"></p>
  </dd>
  <div class="inactive" id="video-2fake"><a>History</a></div>
  <dt><a id="video-2" class="hidden" href="">History</a></dt>
  <dd class="video" id="dd-2">
    <p id="video-message"></p>
    <p id="wistia_id" class="wistia_embed" style="width:640px;height:360px;"></p>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

In the theme functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_video_end', 'updateVideo' );

function video_scripts() {
  $parameters = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('video')
  );

  wp_enqueue_script('video-ajax', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
  wp_localize_script('video-ajax', 'video', $parameters );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'video_scripts');

function ajaxStatus($status, $message, $data = NULL) {

  $response = array (
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => $message,
    'data' => $data
    );
  $output = json_encode($response);

  exit($output);

}

function updateVideo() {

  if(empty($_POST) || !isset($_POST)) {

    ajaxStatus('error', 'Nothing to update.');

  } else {

    $data = $_POST;

    $dataString = $data['post'];
    parse_str($dataString, $dataArray);

    $nonce = $data['nonce'];

    if(wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'video') !== false) {

      $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

      $dataArray['watched'] = isset($dataArray['watched']) ? true : false;

      if($user_ID != NULL) {
        foreach($dataArray as $key=>$value) {

          $status = update_user_meta($user_ID, $key, $value);

        }

        ajaxStatus('success', 'updated', $dataArray);

      } else {
        ajaxStatus('error', 'You are unauthorized to perform this action.', $dataArray);
      }

    } else {

      ajaxStatus('error', 'Nonce check cannot fail.');

    }
  }
}
```

Then the javascript:

```
  video1 = Wistia.embed("");
  video2 = Wistia.embed("");

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var response;

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    if(this)
    return false;
  });

    var watched = '<span>&#9745;</span>',
        visible1 = false,
        visible2 = false,

    $("#dd-1").show();
    video1.bind("end", function () {
      $( "#video-2").removeClass("hidden");
      $( "#video-2fake").hide();
      allPanels.slideUp();
      $("#dd-2").slideDown();

      if(!visible1) {
          $( "#video-1" ).append( watched );
          visible1 = true;
        } 
        else {
          if(visible1) {
            $( "#video-1" ).remove( watched );
            visible1 = false;
          }
        }

       $.post( video.ajaxurl, {
          action : 'video_end',
          nonce : video.nonce,
          post : $(this).serialize()
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            responseSuccess(response);
        });

        return false;

        function responseSuccess(data) {
          response = JSON.parse(data);
          if(response.status === 'success') {
          $('#video-message').text(response.message);
          } else {
          $('#video-message').text(response.message);
          }
         }
    });

    video2.bind("end", function () {
      $( "#video-3").removeClass("hidden");
      $( "#video-3fake").hide();
      allPanels.slideUp();
      $("#dd-3").slideDown();
      position = "2";
      alert(position);
      if(!visible2) {
          $( "#video-2" ).append( watched );
          visible2 = true;
        } 
        else {
          if(visible2) {
            $( "#video-2" ).remove( watched );
            visible2 = false;
          }
        }
        $.post( video.ajaxurl, {
          action : 'video_end',
          nonce : video.nonce,
          post : $(this).serialize()
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            responseSuccess(response);
        });

        return false;

        function responseSuccess(data) {
          response = JSON.parse(data);
          if(response.status === 'success') {
          $('#video-message').text(response.message);
          } else {
          $('#video-message').text(response.message);
          }
         }
   });
  });
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Posted code that i've tried.